# Settings C# dynamic object type name

Tags: c#

I want to save a dynamic object to database. The database table name will be set dynamically. So I have not any class.

```
    private static dynamic CreateModel()
    {
        var model = string.Format("{{'id': '{0} - {1}', 'name':' Path - ', 'length':'{2}' }}", Guid.NewGuid(), DateTime.Now,new Random().NextDouble() * 10 );

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(model);
    }
```

This createsdynamic object. And I am adding this to entity framework generic repository.

```
using (var repository = new EFRepository(new Context()))
{
    repository.SaveOrUpdate<????>(CreateModel())
}
```

I can not set a type name. I can set a random name here.

(`repository.SaveOrUpdate<T>` is a generic method)

Comment: your method signatures does not accept generic type parameter

Comment: If you're using generics, at some point you're going to have to introduce a specific `T`. Any reason why you can't deserialize into a `T` as well?

Comment: Only way you have is to use `Reflection` or use a base type if your entities all inherits from a base type.

Comment: repository.SaveOrUpdate<T> is a generic method

Answer (score 0):

You can't use EF like that.

You can't pass dynamic do the SaveOrUpdate method because `dynamic` can be anything, can be an String, Int or Object. And the compiler you never know this until run the application since `dynamic` types are not resolved in the compilation time but at the run time.

Saying that, as you can image, you can't use dynamic in the generics `<T>` because the T needs to be a reference and the dynamic it's solve at the running time.

I think a better approach where is to use OO to help you with that, creating a base class with an factory to construct your dynamic objects, and use this base class instead of dynamic.